# Anylogic count and store values at data base Table with agent

Tags: anylogic

Anylogic How to count agent enter and leave the charging block with time constraint. I am wondering how to compute the total agent present at charging station .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBas5.png)

Example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `int` variable next to the `charge2` block called `counterIn`.

In the `charge2` block's "on enter" code, write `counterIn++`.

Do the same for exiting and you have your counters.

PS: You may want to clarify/improve your future questions, this one is quite hard to understand. Some tips: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks Benjamin !!! For long run lets say we have 10 AGVs and its going for charging when it need charge depending upon threshold and leaving the charging station. I am using same variable for each AGV entering and leaving the charging station. I have to compute the exact number present at charge station with time constraints. For this purpose, I have to create a database for entering and leaving agent with time. I am wondering how could I create the database with time. Thanks

Comment: Please always start new issues for new questions, SOF does not work like a forum :)

Comment: Thanks, Benjamin very helpful!!! the problem has been resolved.. on enter, I just added counterIn++ and counterIn-- when leaving and used dataset to stored values with time.